# JavaScript RegEx to match "*", unless preceded by backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

Can't seem to get this one — I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that would match a string if it contains "*" in ANY position, but NOT if the asterisk is preceded by a backslash.
For example:

```
abcd: false
*abcd: true
abcde*fghi*: true
abc\*defg: false
\*abcdefg: false
```

I thought I was on the right track with this, but it doesn't work:

```
/[^\\]\*/
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not so simple as it sounds.

What if backslashes themselves are backslashed?

```
 \\* should be true, while
  \* this should be false
```

In fact, the problem is truly a recursive one. But the recursion, look-behind, and all of that complexity can be avoided by thinking about the backslashes themselves, *followed by* the asterisk.

```
/(?:^|[^\\])((\\\\)*\*)/.test(string);
/* returns true for unescaped asterisks */
```

Examples:

```
abcd false
*abcd true
\*abcd false
\\*abcd true
\\\*abcd false
\\\\*abcd true
```

Comment: Hey can you maybe help me with a related question? I'm wondering, how can I split a string on a character (for example the asterisk, doesn't really matter), except when that character was backslashed an odd number of times. I tried to put your regex into a `String.split()`, but it didn't do what I wanted it to and I can't figure out how to make that work. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I wanted to split on the `|` character, here's my code:

`"a|b\\|c\\\\|d".replace(/(^|[^\\])(?:(\\\\)*\|)/g, "$1$2\x00").split("\x00");`

Answer (score 3):

Although in this case a simple `/(^|[^\\])\*/` should do the trick, I like to keep things simpler.

```
var matches = line.indexOf("*") >= 0 && line.indexOf("\\*") < 0;
```

Quite literally: If the line contains `*` and does not contain `\*` then you're good!

Comment: The question states that `\*` is okay as long as there's an asterisk not proceeded by a backslash somewhere else.

Comment: The RegEx works great. I'd rather use it, so I can also use it for matching during a replace. I simple didn't know how to handle the case where the string starts with "*". Thank you!

Comment: @Pluto That could be achieved like so: `matches = line.replace(/\\*/g,'').indexOf("*") >= 0;` - namely, remove all backslashed `*`s and see if there are any `*` left :D

Comment: @fugged The only problem with the regex is that it'll also match the character before, make sure to account for that (everybody only provided answers for testing if that asterisk was there, not for only matching the asterisk).

Comment: Very clever, but this doesn't solve the issue of escaped backslashes.

Comment: @JosephMyers Bugger. Erm... `matches = line.replace(/\\\\/g,'').replace(/\\*/g,'').indexOf("*") >= 0;`? It's getting convoluted now, but still easier than regexes when you don't have recursion or lookbehinds available :D

Answer (score 1):

```
\S*(?:^|[^\\\s])\*\S*
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/32

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should work. In fact, here it is (working) on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iV5lG0/1).

Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds, which is the best way to write this type of regex. So what you have will suffice, although it requires **something** before the asterisk - it can't be the first character.

Comment: `/^\*|[^\\]\*/` works (added `^\*|` to the beginning).

Comment: @nderscore: yes, that's what I explained in the disclaimer - that the asterisk can't be the first character. You provided a complete solution, so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds, but here's a regexp that should work:

`/(?:^|[^\\])\*/`

Explanation:

`(?:^|[^\\])` - non-capturing group to capture either the beginning of the string or a character other than `\`.

`\*` - followed by an asterisk.

Here's a demo with your examples:

```js
var unescapedAsterisk = /(?:^|[^\\])\*/;

['abcd', '*abcd', 'abcde*fghi*', 'abc\\*defg', '\\*abcdefg'].forEach(function(str){
    console.log(str,  unescapedAsterisk.test(str));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the vein of [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html), just use alteration of the type:

```
what I dont want | (what I do want)
```

And then check for the truthiness of group(1)

So, the regex is:

```
\\\*|([^\\]?\*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bI3hZ1/1)

Keep in mind that both sides of the alteration match; you can tell the difference by checking group(1) after the match.